# Laravel 5.5 - multiple images upload

Tags: php, laravel-5, image-uploading

I have this function in my controller:

```
use File;
use Image; //image intervention library
...
public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        //make sure there is a folder in public with the username
        $username = Auth::user()->name;
        $folderpath = public_path('images/' . $username . '/');
        File::makeDirectory($folderpath, $mode = 0777, true, true);

        $files = $request->file;

        if(!empty($files)):
            foreach($files as $file):
                $filename = 'post_' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = $folderpath . $filename;
                Image::make($file)->resize(800,400)->save($path);
            endforeach;
        endif;

        return 'success';
    }
```

which only save the last image if I upload multiple.

and I tried:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        //make sure there is a folder in public with the username
        $username = Auth::user()->name;
        $folderpath = public_path('images/' . $username . '/');
        File::makeDirectory($folderpath, $mode = 0777, true, true);

        $files = $request->file;

        if(!empty($files)):
            foreach($files as $file):
                $filename = 'post_' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = $folderpath . $filename;
                $file->save($path);
            endforeach;
        endif;

        return ''success;
    }
```

which throw me error:

> Method save does not exist.

I goggled and it seems like I did not instantiate it with model. But in this case, how can I instantiate it with model if it is just a direct file upload?

What is the best way for multiple images upload in `laravel`?

**Update**

After reading @kunal's answer, I managed to solve the issue by adding a unique number for the file name:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        //make sure there is a folder in public with the username
        $username = Auth::user()->name;
        $folderpath = public_path('images/' . $username . '/');
        File::makeDirectory($folderpath, $mode = 0777, true, true);

        $files = $request->file;
        $count = 0;//<-- add a counter
        if(!empty($files)):
            foreach($files as $file):
                $filename = 'post_' . time() . '_' . $count . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();//<-- add counter to the file name
                $path = $folderpath . $filename;
                Image::make($file)->resize(800,400)->save($path);
                $count ++;//<-- increase the value
            endforeach;
        endif;

        return 'success';
    }
```

Comment: u want multiple images for single user? with out repeat the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are looking for this kind of stuff:-

```
if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
$files = $request->file('files');
foreach($files as $file){
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileName = str_random(5)."-".date('his')."-".str_random(3).".".$extension;
    $folderpath  = 'images'.'/';
    $file->move($folderpath , $fileName);
}
}
<input type="file" id="gallery" name="files[]" multiple />
```

Comment: your code is not exactly what i am looking for, however `str_random(5)` did solve my problem. I just keep my own code as it is then add `$count` to the `$filename` and `$count++;` in the loop and my problem is solved. Please check my update.

Comment: @sooon hehehh glad to help my str_random help you :P

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking u may missed this part

```
<input type="file" id="gallery" name="file[]" />
```

note the `file[]` it must be array otherwise it will `only save the last image if upload multiple image`

If u did ur html part correct, then use like this,

```
foreach ($file as $photo) {
    $path = Storage::putFile('foldername', $photo);
}
```

Comment: When did the OP add html code? How do you know that OP missed it?

Comment: i assumed it, by the line he mentioned `which only save the last image`

Comment: @arunkumar your answer is not my issue but i think is valuable because it is some mistake beginner like me can always miss out.

Comment: yup, understood!

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
$files= Input::file('image');
$destinationPath= 'images';
$images=array(); 
foreach($files as $file){
    $fullname= $file->getClientOriginalName(); 
    $hashname  = $fullname; 
    $upload_success   =$file->move($destinationPath, $hashname);
    $images[]=$fullname;
    $has= implode(",",$images);
}
$modelname= new Modelname;
$modelname->image_attachment    =  $has;  
$modelname->save();
```

and yout html page:

```
<input type="file" id="image" name="image[]" />
```

Comment: how u make this? make($file)->resize(800,400);with ur code?

Comment: Iam trying to this way and save the resize images

Comment: foreach($files as $file){
             $fullname = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $path = public_path('images/' . $imageName);
            Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(800,400)              
                          ->save($path);
            $images[]=$fullname;
            $has= implode(",",$images);
              }

Answer (score 0):

It is not that complicated.
As of larval 5.8 you can do this:

```
collect($request->images)->each(function ($image) {
    return $image->store('images', 'public');
});
```

It puts images in images folder of public disk.